# How are system calls called?

Tags: python, operating-system, kernel, system-calls, libc

So I understand what system calls are for and what they do. Pretty much anything that requires a computer's resources invokes a system call at some point. My question is, how does a user-created program in Python for example compile and know where to make system calls? If I write a "Hello World" program, does the compiler (interpreter in this case) know to associate the print() function in Python with a particular system call in its host operating system? Where in the process of writing a user program in a programming language and turning it into 1s and 0s do system calls come into play? Thanks.

Comment: Python interpreter is linked with `libc` library and calls its function. `libc` library in turn performs system calls. You may easily google about both these aspects.

Answer (score 3):

> how does a user-created program in Python for example compile and know where to make system calls?

You can explore some of this yourself.

Given this Python program: `print("Hello")`, on a UNIX system one can guess that a `write(2)` system call will eventually be invoked. Let's see if that's true:

```
gdb -q --args python -c 'print("Hello")'

(gdb) catch syscall write
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'write' [1])

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/python -c print\(\"Hello\"\)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall write), 0x00007ffff6f3cdd4 in __GI___libc_write (fd=1, buf=0x555555b2f9f0, nbytes=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:26
26      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) x/s $rsi
0x555555b2f9f0: "Hello\n"

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6f3cdd4 in __GI___libc_write (fd=1, buf=0x555555b2f9f0, nbytes=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:26
#1  0x00007ffff6ecdb9d in _IO_new_file_write (f=0x7ffff720d760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x555555b2f9f0, n=6) at fileops.c:1183
#2  0x00007ffff6eccf3f in new_do_write (fp=0x7ffff720d760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x555555b2f9f0 "Hello\n", to_do=to_do@entry=6) at libioP.h:839
#3  0x00007ffff6ecece9 in _IO_new_do_write (fp=<optimized out>, data=<optimized out>, to_do=6) at fileops.c:432
#4  0x00007ffff6ece26f in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff720d760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=1) at libioP.h:839
#5  0x00007ffff6ec2c3f in __GI__IO_fputs (str=0x55555580d74d "\n", fp=0x7ffff720d760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at libioP.h:839
#6  0x00005555556966ac in PyFile_WriteString ()
#7  0x000055555564c42d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#8  0x000055555564610a in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#9  0x0000555555645a29 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#10 0x0000555555676c5f in ?? ()
#11 0x00005555556a4846 in PyRun_StringFlags ()
#12 0x00005555556a567c in PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ()
#13 0x000055555562005a in Py_Main ()
#14 0x00007ffff6e7652b in __libc_start_main (main=0x55555561fb30 <main>, argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdc78, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffdc68) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#15 0x000055555561fa4a in _start ()
```

What can you deduce from this?

1. The `write` system call is indeed invoked, with expected characters in the `$RSI` register (which happens to be where the second argument to system calls must be for this particular platform).
2. The system call is invoked from `__GI___libc_write` routine, which is a system call *wrapper* provided by `libc`.
3. Python did not call `__libc_write` directly. It called `__GI__IO_fputs` (which is actually an alias for `fputs`.
4. The Python *interpreter* translated the `print` into a call to `PyFile_WriteString`, and that function delegated the actual work to libc.

This is not at all unusual -- in fact most user-level programs do not execute system calls directly. Instead, they call `libc` routines, such as `write` or `fputs`, and let the libc worry how to implement these routines in terms of system calls.

By doing so, they can *abstract* the details of the particular machine and OS; they expect to find some `libc` on any machine, and only `libc` developers have to worry about actual system call details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why are there so many different avenues for invoking the system call? As in, what is different about __GI___libc_write, __GI__IO_fputs, and PyFile_WriteString?

Comment: @NDrummerboy087 "why are there so many different avenues for invoking the system call?" -- I don't think you understood the answer. There is only one place that *actually* invokes the system call. Everything else is *delegating* the work, in order to *abstract* away from the details.